# Determining whether a polyhedral cone is a subset of another polyhedral cone

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, decision-problems

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. The polyhedral cones of $A$ and $B$ are given by $$\mathcal{C}_A = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x = A \lambda, \mbox{ where } \lambda_i \ge 0 \mbox{ for all } i = 1, 2, \ldots n\}, $$ and $$\mathcal{C}_B = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x = B \lambda, \mbox{ where } \lambda_i \ge 0 \mbox{ for all } i = 1, 2, \ldots n\},$$ respectively. The polyhedral cones are all of the linear combinations of the columns of the corresponding matrix with non-negative weights.

Let $\pi_{i,j} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the matrix which projects $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto its $i^{\text{th}}$ and $j^{\text{th}}$ coordinates.

**Question:** If $\pi_{i,j}( \mathcal{C}_A ) \subset \pi_{i,j} (\mathcal{C}_B)$ for every $i \neq j$, then is it necessarily true that $\mathcal{C}_A \subset \mathcal{C}_B$?

It is fairly easy to come up with a counter example for arbitrary sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for example [these two ellipses in $\mathbb{R}^3$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v29X.jpg), but I have not been able to find a counter example when the sets are polyhedral cones. In any counterexample I can find, the intersection between the two sets is being "hidden" from the projection down to the coordinate planes. My intuition is that this is not possible for polyhedral cones. Can anyone prove that this is true or produce a counter example?

**Edit:** copper.hat found a counterexample where $\pi_{i,j}( \mathcal{C}_A ) = \pi_{i,j} (\mathcal{C}_B)$ for all $i,j$. Does a counterexample still exist for the statement

If $\pi_{i,j}( \mathcal{C}_A ) \subsetneq \pi_{i,j} (\mathcal{C}_B)$ for all $i,j$, then $\mathcal{C}_A \subset \mathcal{C}_B$?

Comment: Just a question: for checking if one cone is contained in the other, does it not suffice to check if each of the basis vectors is in the cone of the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 2 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$,
$B =\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Then the projections are all the same but the cones are different.

Comment: Thanks for answering this @copper.hat. I agree that this is a counterexample where $\pi_{i,j}(\mathcal{C}_A) = \pi_{i,j}(\mathcal{C}_B)$ for all $i,j$. What if the question is strengthened to $\pi_{i,j}(\mathcal{C}_A) \subsetneq \pi_{i,j}(\mathcal{C}_B)$ for all $i,j$?

Comment: This has become a wandering question. If $C_A \subset C_B$ then the projections must have the same ordering. So it is impossible for the projections to not have the same order.

Comment: I apologize for the wandering question, @copper.hat. I don't understand your argument for $\pi_{i,j} ( \mathcal{C}_A ) \subsetneq \pi_{i,j} ( \mathcal{C}_B )$. If I'm understanding properly, you are saying that the converse of the statement is true (which I agree with!), but this doesn't mean that the original statement is true. Just to be clear- I am intending $A \subsetneq B$ to mean that $A \subset B$ but $A \neq B$.

Comment: is the correct etiquette in this case to accept your answer and open a new question?

Comment: If any projection is not contained then the original sets **cannot** be contained. So, the answer to your last question is no.

Comment: If you add a clarification of a question then an edit is sufficient. If you are asking a new question then a new question is needed. In the case above, the answer is straightforward, so I would not bother.

Comment: If $\pi_{i,j}( \mathcal{C}_A ) \subsetneq \pi_{i,j} ( \mathcal{C}_B )$, then every projection of $\mathcal{C}_A$ is (strictly) contained within the corresponding projection of $\mathcal{C}_B$. So there are no projections that are not contained.

Comment: Excuse, me, I misread.